# Overlapping images on google cloud platform

Tags: html, css, image, google-cloud-platform, overlapping

I've deployed a website using google cloud, but for some reason the images are overlapping with the content, while the local version has no problems. Are there any automatic settings from google cloud ? Does anyone know what might be the problem ? I've tried pretty much every option available as far as html/css and still no result.

Comment: please can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I actually resolved it today, it turned about that for some reason Google Cloud doesn't "like" $(document).ready. Instead, when I replaced it with $(windon).load it it fixed the issue and the website looks great. Thank you for reaching out though! Appreciate it.